# Vertically aligning code in visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, resharper, vertical-alignment, visual-studio-2017, code-formatting

I found that the productivity tools do not do quite what I am looking for them to do.
Currently they will align all assignments (as the extension says it will do) while I am looking for something that will fully align my code.

Is there anything that will turn this:

```
string _name = "John";
int _age = 20;
private double _velocity {get; set;} = 3.3;
```

Into this:

```
        string   _name                    =  "John";
        int      _age                     =      20;
private double   _velocity  {get; set;}   =     3.3;
```

I have ReSharper installed but have not found anything in the settings that suggests it can do this.

Answer (score 1):

Free [Code alignment](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cpmcgrath.Codealignment) Visual Studio extention can format code vertically.

However, it is not so smart as it could be. To achieve formatting you described, first select "Align by string" at the extention's toolbar and input `_` character. Then choose "Align by equals".

You could customize and simplify the toolbar's buttons behavior:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was about to start trying to make an extension that would do this. Would it still function if the members do not start with _?

Comment: @DimitryRakhlei yes, it would. https://github.com/cpmcgrath/codealignment/wiki/Align-by-space